Poisson conditional probability and i'm unsure
I am a student studying statistics and encountered a question of the following and I'm not sure if I am doing well.
Let $S_1, S_2, S_3 ⋯$ be the time of buses arriving and it is known that $S_i$ follows exponential distribution of λ=1. Here, get the conditional probability of $S_1, S_2, S_3, S_4$ given $S_5 = 10$.
I used this method: Let N(t) is the number of buses who arrive in t time. Then N(t) ~ Pois(t).
Then $P(S_1 = a, S_2 = b, S_3 = c, S_4 = d | S_5 = 10) = \frac{N(a) = 1, N(b-a)=1, N(c-b)=1, N(d-c)=1, N(10-d)=1}{N(10)=5}$.
Will this yield the right result?

Did you mean to say that $S_i$ = the time between (i-1) th and i th bus, is exponentially distributed. And that sum over $S_i$ =5?

No Si=the time past until the ith bus arrives.

Ok, if, you define $S_i$ like that, then you missed that it is the time between busses that is exponentially distributed, not the arrival time itself.

Oh then how should I make the formula?

See this question.
